# What is meant by a Ether Wallet?

Tags: wallets

Somebody please tell me what is a Ether Wallet?

I got the following answer:

> A blockchain wallet is a digital wallet that allows users to manage
>   bitcoin and ether.

Is it like a account?

Zulfi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term "wallet" can be used in many different ways, but most commonly it is used to refer to interface or application to manage an account or address, such as [MyCrypto](https://mycrypto.com/) or [MetaMask](https://metamask.io/). With a wallet, you can generate a private key (or mnemonic phrase, keystore file, etc.), and use the software to send transactions and sign messages.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend checking out the book "[Mastering Bitcoin](https://github.com/bitcoinbook/bitcoinbook)", specifically [Chapter 5](https://github.com/bitcoinbook/bitcoinbook/blob/develop/ch05.asciidoc)to learn more about wallets:

> The word "wallet" is used to describe a few different things in
>   bitcoin.
>
> At a high level, a wallet is an application that serves as the primary
>   user interface. The wallet controls access to a user’s money, managing
>   keys and addresses, tracking the balance, and creating and signing
>   transactions.
>
> More narrowly, from a programmer’s perspective, the word "wallet"
>   refers to the data structure used to store and manage a user’s keys.

You can hold different accounts in a wallet. Some even allow different types of ERC20 tokens, or different cryptocurrencies. Another good way to learn about wallets is to download one and try it out. [MetaMask](https://metamask.io/) can be installed in the browser, and you can get some test Ether at a [faucet like this one](https://faucet.rinkeby.io/).